# Add text to image, then save to gallery

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am developing a Xamarin.Form application which is adding some text to an image, and I have to save that image to gallery. Can someone help me what is the best way to do that?

NB: I have 3 text sentence to add in the image text sentence are fixed position. Kindly find the sample/example given below.

So far i have added the text (code given below) to my image and given the position to it. Now i have to save that image to gallery.

[image: Example Image]

```
 <AbsoluteLayout  Grid.Row="0" MinimumHeightRequest="370" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
    <Image x:Name="backgroundImage" Source="wcc_background.jpg" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"   AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Aspect="AspectFit"/>


    <Grid  x:Name="grdView" HeightRequest="370" WidthRequest="370" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" >

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="120" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <StackLayout Padding="0,0,40,0"  HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="End" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >
            <Label Text="{Binding Item.Title}"   HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="End"  Font="Bold,Medium"  />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout  HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
            <Label VerticalTextAlignment="End" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" XAlign="End" Text="{Binding Item.Description}" Font="Small" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout  HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
            <Label Text="Reference"  Font="Micro" />
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout  HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
            <Label Text="{Binding Item.Reference}"  Font="Micro" />
        </StackLayout>


    </Grid>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: So far i have added the text to the image using Absolutelayout  and created grid inside it and added the text.

Comment: We need to see the existing code for how you load and modify the image otherwise the question is far to broad

Comment: @AshleyMedway As per your request i have edited the question with the existing code what i have done.

Comment: Yeah so your issue is going to be that you are not modifying the original image in anyway you are just visually laying text over the image. You need to be using a graphics package.

Comment: @AshleyMedway Which Graphics Package do you recommend ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for recommendations, you need to do the research yourself, sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161186/discussion-between-anurag-and-ashley-medway).